# How should I define a DAX measure to normalize dataset values by category in a time series visual?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to obtain a plot of values by categories, normalized by
the category value at the earliest date not sooner than a selected date from a time slicer.

I tried to the following DAX measure:

```
Normalized = 
    var mintime = CALCULATE(min(Data[Date]), ALLSELECTED(Data))
    var initial = SUMX(FILTER(ALLSELECTED(Data), Data[Date]=mintime), Data[Value])
    return DIVIDE(SUM(Data[Value]), initial)
```

But this fails to correctly compute the initial values per category, and correspondingly the lines do not start at 1 on the graph.
For example, using a sample dataset `Data` defined as:

```
      Date Category  Value
2022-01-01        A    100
2022-01-01        B     95
2022-01-02        A     60
2022-01-02        B    115
2022-01-02        C     95
2022-01-03        A     36
2022-01-03        B     34
2022-01-03        C     54
2022-01-04        A     22
2022-01-04        B     10
2022-01-04        C     27
```

I get the following incorrect plot:

[image: Plot of incorrectly normalized data: series A, B & C are divided by the sum of values for all categories, yielding plots which do not start at 1.0]

How should I modify my measure to get the correct result?

For reference, I know I could separate the data in computed tables for each category:

```
TableA = FILTER(Data, Data[Category] == "A")
TableB = FILTER(Data, Data[Category] == "B")
TableC = FILTER(Data, Data[Category] == "C")
```

Then define separate DAX measures for each category:

```
A = 
    var mintime = CALCULATE(min(TableA[Date]), ALLSELECTED(TableA))
    var initial = SUMX(FILTER(ALLSELECTED(TableA), TableA[Date]=mintime), TableA[Value])
    return DIVIDE(SUM(TableA[Value]), initial)
B = ...
```

Along with relationships to keep all the `TableA[Date]`, `TableB[Date]`, ... to refer to a common time base.
Stacking each of those measures into a line plot does produce the expected result:

[image: Plot of correctly normalized data: series A, B & C start at 1.0 on Jan/01, Jan/01 and Jan/02 respectively when slicer starts on Jan/01; all series also start at 1.0 on Jan/02 when slicer starts on Jan/02]

However this quickly become fairly impractical as the number of categories increases (and my production dataset does have much more categories).
So I'm looking for an alternative approach involving a single measure, contextualized by the plot legend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turns out to be related to the effect of `ALLSELECTED` when used as
either a `CALCULATE` modifier with a table argument, with a column argument or
as a table function.
For more information, a pretty detailed discussion on the topic can be found
[in this blog on www.sqlbi.com](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/the-definitive-guide-to-allselected/).

***Computing the earliest date of a category***

The usage of `ALLSELECTED(Data)` when computing `mintime` as

```
var mintime = CALCULATE(min(Data[Date]), ALLSELECTED(Data))
```

is a `CALCULATE` modifier with a table argument.
The behavior of `ALLSELECTED` is then to resolve to the the explicit filter of
the `CALCULATE` expression.
Since the only explicit filter in this case is the page's time slider, that's
the only filtering being applied.
This results in the variable `mintime` holding the minimum time over all
categories (subject only to the slider), regardless of the applicable category.

On the other hand, using `ALLSELECTED` with `Data[Date]` column argument
would make use of the implicit category filter created while the measure
evaluation iterates through the dates (as well as any explicit filter on the page).
Thus, to get the earliest date amongst the values of a given category,
the following should be used:

```
var mintime = CALCULATE(MIN(Data[Date]), ALLSELECTED(Data[Date]))
```

***Computing the initial value at earliest date of a category***

Similarly, the usage of `ALLSELECTED(Data)` when computing `initial` in

```
var mintime = CALCULATE(MIN(Data[Date]), ALLSELECTED(Data))
var initial = SUMX(FILTER(ALLSELECTED(Data), Data[Date]=mintime), Data[Value])
```

is a table function, which results in only the explicit slider filter to be
applied. This gives an `initial` value that is the sum over all categories.
To retain the implicit filter, we should consider using a `Data[Date]` column
argument instead. However in this expression this would also reduce the available dataset for the
`SUMX` function, rendering the `Data[Value]` reference invalid.
To get around this we can then rewrite the expression in two steps: first
filter the data based on the date, then use `CALCULATE` to compute the
corresponding value:

```
var initial = CALCULATE(SUM(Data[Value]), FILTER(ALL(Data[Date]),Data[Date]=mintime))
```

We should note at this point that using `ALL` or `ALLSELECTED` as a table function
in the `FILTER` context yields the same result, since the actual filtering by
category occurs within the outer `CALCULATE` loop.
This brings us to the shorter equivalent form (as shown [here](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/managing-all-functions-in-dax-all-allselected-allnoblankrow-allexcept/#code1)):

```
var initial = CALCULATE(SUM(Data[Value]), Data[Date]=mintime)
```

***Conclusion***

To get the correct result the measure can be modified as follows:

```
Normalized = 
    var mintime = CALCULATE(MIN(Data[Date]), ALLSELECTED(Data[Date]))
    var initial = CALCULATE(SUM(Data[Value]), Data[Date]=mintime)
    return DIVIDE(SUM(Data[Value]),initial)
```

[image: Plot of correctly normalized data: series A, B & C start at 1.0 on Jan/01, Jan/01 and Jan/02 respectively when slicer starts on Jan/01; all series also start at 1.0 on Jan/02 when slicer starts on Jan/02]